# How to pass two arguments in a url with (?P<pk>\d+)$'

Tags: python, html, django

In the code below referring to django's urls.py file, I'm passing the **pk** as an argument in the url:

```
url(r'^data/edit_item/(?P<pk>\d+)$', edit_data, name="edit_data")
```

I want to know if there is a way to pass two arguments in this kind of regular expression. I've tried several ways like:

```
url(r'^data/edit_item/(?P<pk>\d+)$&header', edit_data, name="edit_data")
```

but I'm having a lot of trouble getting the right format.

The url is being called directly in the html:

```
{% if header|lower == "specie" %}

    <a href="{% url 'edit_data' item.pk %}" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > Edit</a>

{% endif %}
```

So I need to pass the argument **header** in the html as well:

```
{% if header|lower == "specie" %}

    <a href="{% url 'edit_data' item.pk header %}" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > Edit</a>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `from django.urls import path`:

```py
path('data/edit_item/<slug:pk>/<slug:header>/', edit_data, name="edit_data")
```

If you want to use url with regex, try this:

```py
url(r'^data/edit_item/(?P<pk>\S+)/(?P<header\S+)/', edit_data, name="edit_data")
```